# ajax control toolkit & sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I was trying to use ajax control toolkit in sharepoint 2010, but i get some errors. I found that the last release of the toolkit doesn't work with SP2010, so i downloaded the version 30930 found at http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/33804
Then i modified the web.config adding this:

```
<assemblies>
  ....
  <add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30930.28736, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" />
```

I added the dll to the references (creating a new tab in the toolbox and browsing the dll file) and started using the ajax controls in my web part. It deploys without problems, but when i run my webpage i get this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.40412.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Which points to the first line of my webpart ascx file

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your web part references version 3.5.40412.0 of the AJAX Control Toolkit in an `@Register` directive. Since you want to use version 3.0.30930.28736, and since that version is properly referenced in your `web.config`, you should register the toolkit in your web part using its assembly name and namespace only, e.g.:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
    TagPrefix="ajax" %>
```

Comment: I did't understand exactly what do you mean. Anyway, i've repeated the process, and this time works! I think it's because the first time i imported the ajax toolkit, i used the latest release (which isn't working), and therafter i have never modified the dll in the references. By removing it completely and by adding the older release dll to the references, it all works fine now =)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this blog article which explains how to use the Ajax Control Toolkit with SharePoint 2010 http://www.inspiredbytechnology.com/index.php/2010/10/28/using-the-ajax-control-toolkit-with-sharepoint-2010/