# How to register Ajax Tool Kit to SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've tried to use Ajax Control Tool Kits on SharePoint 2010 Web Site, but Im having some trouble with registration. I've searched a lot on google for a solution. I've found some ways, but my problem is not solved. When I open my web site, still getting registration error.
[image]

The problem is registration of Ajax Tool Kit. Here is my steps.

1 - Downloaded Ajax Control Tool Kit latest version.

2 - Added following line to my page

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30930.28736, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

3 - Added following line to my master page (v4.master)

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30930.28736, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

4 - Replaced this tag

```
<asp:ScriptManager>
```

with

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

but problem not solved..  Still getting same registration error. I need your suggestions about implementing Ajax Control Tool Kits on Share Point 2010. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This SO answer might help [ajax control toolkit & sharepoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922167/ajax-control-toolkit-sharepoint-2010)