# additional ddl ( Ajax Control Toolkit ) could not be deployed in sharepoint

Tags: c#, ajax, sharepoint, controls, toolkit

Hello I used this [tutorial](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/ajax-control-toolkit-with-sharepoint.html) to deploy Ajax Control Toolkit assemblies to sharepoint server. It is ok when I did deployment in my local configuration. But I cannot deploy the project including the package that have this Toolkit. The error message is not telling too much:

> "Error 1 Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application
>   Pool': The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout
>   of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a
>   portion of a longer timeout."

What could be the reason? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions 1.0 (which ever is compatible with your tool kit.). Also try to install `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` in the GAC.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I tried to install Ajax Toolkit with gacutil command, it isn't worked either.
I couldn't understand what you've meant to "need to Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions 1.0", I do not have a problem with compiling, it's just not deployed

Comment: Did you mark toolkit as safe control, check on net how to do that. Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922167/ajax-control-toolkit-sharepoint-2010) post.