# AjaxControlsToolkit in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to add the AjaxControlsToolkit reference to the default.master, so first I added the dll to the GAC. Next I've added this to the SafeControl assembly

```
<SafeControl Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.40412.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e, processorArchitecture=MSIL" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TypeName="*" Safe="True" AllowRemoteDesigner="True" />
```

Then in my default.master I've added the register assembly directive and the script manager tag (inside form tag.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %><ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
```

When I run it, I get an "An unexpected error has occured." If I remove the line of code from safe controls, I get "The control type 'AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager' is not allowed on this page. The type is not registered as safe. "

As I'm typing this, I just noticed that there already is a

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />
```

So conflict perhaps? I need the Ajax toolkit for some custom webparts I'm bringing in from MOSS 2007 and in my research I've not seen any langauage wheather Ajax in integrated in SP2010 so I'm just doing what I've done many times in MOSS 2007.

What is one to do?

Thanks,

Risho

Answer (score 0):

> What is one to do?

Do a search on this forum?

[ajax control toolkit & sharepoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922167/ajax-control-toolkit-sharepoint-2010)

Or a Google search perhaps?

[How to use AjaxControlToolkit in share point 2010?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepoint2010programming/thread/ad875ab2-12db-4c42-9cb0-d4494a0f1776)